# China has patent

Tags: patent-infringement

What  happens if you manufacture something that someone else has a patent on. A company in China has a patent on the  product  that I also thought  of and would like  to make. To date the other company has  not began producing  the  product.

Comment: In what countries does the Chinese company have patents in?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, (for most jurisdictions, including the US, Europe, China)

*a (granted) patent gives you the right to exclude others from selling, making, offering, etc. the patented invention in the country where the patent is granted.*

Neither the nationality of the applicant nor the question if they are using the invention make any difference.

=> If the Chinese company has a patent in any place that you intend to manufacture or sell your product at, you're infringing the patent and might be sued for damages and/or liable to pay royalties. In other words, if they have a US-patent and you intend to produce or sell there, you'll be infringing the patent.